# How to keep Laravel Auth routes with vuejs routing?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, laravel-7, laravel-sanctum

As I've seen in many tutorials, I used the following code to be able to use the vue-router:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('home');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

I'm using `sanctum` and I would like to keep using the `Auth::routes()` that comes with laravel, but they don't work anymore.

I guess I have to change the `{any}` pattern with something else, but with what exactly?

Best

Comment: hm I am under the assumption that you should define the more specific routes first, which is what you did. Try `php artisan route:list` and see what it says.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I decided to simply route everything after `/app` via Vue, the rest will go through laravel.

I went to `app->providers->RouteServiceProvider.php` and updated the following line as:

```
public const HOME = '/app/home';
```

The routing would look like this in Laravel (mention the 'app'):

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/app/{any}', function () {
    return view('app');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

If someone has a better workaround, please let me know!